# angularJS - loading a web page inside a div tag

Tags: angularjs, html

I have seen this question in STO but could not find a proper answer.

I am using angular 1.0 and sending an AJAX request to server to get a list of URLs like below format:

https://www.abc.info/tawasol-news/20830168
https://www.abc.info/tawasol-news/20830169
https://www.abc.info/tawasol-news/20830174

and I want to load these URLs in a set of div tags down another.
but I can not see a clear solution how achieve that. please help to to load these URLs inside a div where we can scroll and view item by item.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using `object` element in your HTML (div).

```
<object type="text/html" data="your url"></object>
```

See Mozilla documentation for object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object).

Comment: I used <object> in my AngularJs applicaton and it worked well on Chrome. Also, it seems to be compatible with Chrome according to the specification. Check the example at https://jsfiddle.net/Lc4a1vfb/8/ You can see it works on Chrome.

Comment: Hey, great it works bro. should be my mistake. Thanks again for your help.